# Bootstrap alert dismissible not working on Blazor client side (webassembly)

Tags: c#, blazor-client-side

I'm testing C# Blazor webassembly for a small project. I got this sample from bootstrap website but on .razor webpage the close functionality isn't working, anyone having same issue?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/#dismissing

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Put this in any Blazor Page the dismiss button don't work. This sample is exactly the sample of the link above.

Comment: Add sample code

Comment: `Be sure you’ve loaded the alert plugin, or the compiled Bootstrap JavaScript.`

Comment: Thanks, the webassembly template for Blazor came with bootstrap.css but not with the .js files, I added bootstrap and jquery javascript files and now works fine, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Add below script tag and make sure to have the file exist in that path

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```